# how to fetch count of items in relation table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

i have two mysql db tables 'tags' and 'tags_used'. i have added images for checking the db structure.currently iam using laravel fluent query builder.
Now what i want to query is the count of rows in relation table like below. Please help me with either laravel fluent query or plain sql query.

```
id    | name  |times_used
------------
1 | tag1 | 3
------------
2 | tag2 | 1
------------
3 | tag3 | 5
------------
4 | tag4 | 1
------------
5 | tag5 | 0
------------
----------
```

[image: tags structure]

[image]

Comment: Why does your result have multiple rows for the same tag?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: @Barmar : sorry that was a mistake in question, i'll update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables, and `COUNT()` to count the matches.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, IFNULL(COUNT(u.id), 0) AS times_used
FROM tags AS t
LEFT JOIN tags_used AS u ON t.id = u.tags_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Note that you have to use `COUNT(u.id)` rather than `COUNT(*)` so you don't count the row with null values in the `tags_used` columns when there's no matches.